# java 1.7 compatibility with jdbc driver

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am new user with java and finally got my code to work and tried transporting it to a remote machine as a jar to run and started getting the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection <init> SEVERE: Java Runtime Environment 
(JRE) version 1.8 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, 
which provides support for JDBC 4.0.java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 
Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.8 is not supported by this driver. Use 
 the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.<init>
    (SQLServerConn
```

I updated the driver in the build path and still does not work. It runs fine on my desktop so not sure what the issue is. Please advise as to what is the best approach here.

EDIT:

The snapshot I posted above shows 1.8 but i have tried it on  several 1.7 machine versions.

[image: cJYJe.png]

and also connection code

```
    String dataConnectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.xxx.x.xxx:1433;" +
             "databaseName=clientsDB;user=me;password=notyou";
```

Comment: Are you in fact using sqljdbc4.jar?

Comment: edit above shows current library in build path

Comment: yes I would assume so as it is in the build path

Comment: No, that's sqljdbc4-3.0.jar, which is presumably v3.0 of the driver. Try the download link on the page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx) for the v4.0 driver.

Comment: thanks for the response. I did originally have sqljdbc4.jar and it didn't work then tried the above version. I will retry with the new download you provided.

Comment: I changed the way I was creating the jar by including packaged libraries and for some reason that worked...thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server (sqljdbc4.jar), available via the download link on the page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx), is indeed compatible with both JRE 7 and JRE 8. I just confirmed Java 8 compatibility on an Xubuntu 14.04 box with

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I changed the way I was creating the jar by including packaged libraries and for some reason that worked...thanks though. So it wasn't actually the jdbc jar itself...sounds weird but at least it worked.

Comment: Comment about newer Ms JDBC driver versions. 
Version **4.2 requires at least Java 8** (1.8). It is not mentioned in download page but only here [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378422.aspx]